# Next.js unresponsive after deployment to Azure/Vercel

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, nextjs

After deploying next.js app to Azure/Vercel the site becomes unresponsive. I tried the site on a browser without wallet and the site works fine. After installing phantom to the browser the site works now but it refreshes every few seconds. After few refreshes the site is unresponsive again. After removing phantom from browser and refreshing site works fine again. On local environment the application works just fine. When I tried it with plain react application everything was working fine but on nextjs when I deploy I experience this issue.

This is my _app.tsx. [image]